# How can I get kobject and kset in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, sysfs

I want to get the kobject and kset struct of /sys/fs/f2fs in Linux kernel.
I tried the following method:

```
kset_find_obj(fs_kobj->kset, "f2fs")
```

But null pointer error happened.

`fs_kobj->kset` seems to be null.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I find a method as below:

```
struct kernfs_node *node = kernfs_find_and_get(fs_kobj->sd, "f2fs");
struct kobject *kobj = (struct kobject *)(node->priv);
```